# In case about physical link problems with Google (GGC) who can help me?

Tags: google-cdn, google-cloud-cdn, google-cloud-interconnect

A month ago I sent an email to noc@google.com stating that the interface connecting our equipment and Google equipment is down. Since then I've started sending emails daily asking about updates and always give me the same response from the organization:

"Hello Team,
 
This issue is pending with Century link they had an outage at Brazil.
Once we get updates from them we will share with you shortly. "

It looks like an automatic response. In the case of remote-hans the only means of support for Google CDN is only via email noc@google.com?

Comment: And what is your question or would you like to start a blog here?

Comment: Because Google directed me to ask here.
https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/getting-support

Comment: And again what is your question and if you should ask there, why are you asking here?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can file tickets related to your GGC nodes using Google's ISP Portal. There's more information at https://support.google.com/interconnect/answer/9058810.